# Password salt and PBKDF2

Tags: codeigniter, passwords, codeigniter-2, pbkdf2

I'm looking into different solutions regarding storing passwords in Database. After reading a lot I think i will end up with **PBKDF2**.

Although I'm a little bit confused regarding if I should input salt to my PBKDF2 function and store the salt in a column and the PBKDF2'd password in another column.

I'm also using CodeIgniter and found a library for PBKDF2 (https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library) Which claims I don't need to store the salt separately.

> Register user by using `$pbkdf2['hash']` as user's password which has
>   been recommended; no need to store user's salt separately.
>
> https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library#step-2

So if I'm assuming correct all I need is to provide a password into the function and the function take care of the rest?

Comment: Why don't you use PHP's native API for hashing passwords? The function [password_hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) will create BCrypt hashes and is "future proof".

Answer (score 5):

I'm the creator of **[CodeIgniter PBKDF2 Library](https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library)**. Just found this topic on SO, and I decide to clarify how this library works.

Here is the sample code from the doc:

```php
# Load pbkdf2 library into your controller
$this->load->library('pbkdf2');

# Get password, which has been sent via POST method
$password = $this->input->post('password');

# Encrypt the given password using a random generated salt
$pbkdf2 = $this->pbkdf2->encrypt($password);
```

The `encrypt()` method, [returns an array](https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library/blob/master/libraries/Pbkdf2.php#L273-L277) which has 3 keys: `salt`, `password`, `hash`. 
The value of `hash` is the concatenation of `salt` and `password`.

This feature lets the user to choose how to use this library, whether to work with *salt* and *password* or *hash* (*salt* + *password*).

### The syntax of `encrypt()` method:

```php
encrypt( string $password [, mixed $good_hash = NULL [, bool $object_output = FALSE]] )
```

The function uses the given *`$good_hash`* [as the **salt**](https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library/blob/master/libraries/Pbkdf2.php#L254-L255) to generate the encrypted **password**. And it uses a **random** generated *salt* if the *`$good_hash`* parameter is not given.

So, If you have stored the `salt` separately, you could pass it to the function as the second parameter to encrypt the given password:

```php
$pbkdf2 = $this->pbkdf2->encrypt($password, $salt);
```

**On the other hand**, If you have stored the concatenation of `salt` and `password` into database, you could pass that to the function as the second parameter, too:

```php
$pbkdf2 = $this->pbkdf2->encrypt($password, $hash);
```

The function [will break the given `$hash`](https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library/blob/master/libraries/Pbkdf2.php#L256-L257) automatically to fetch the `salt`.

So, you could store the concatenation of *salt* and *password* in a column ([64 characters by default](https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library/blob/master/libraries/Pbkdf2.php#L51-L58)) and then encrypt the new given password by using old stored one.

## Putting all together

In the following, I'll show you how to work with this library to register/login the user, without storing the *salt* and the *password* separately.

#### Registering the user:

```php
$this->load->library('pbkdf2');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$pbkdf2 = $this->pbkdf2->encrypt($password);

# Store $pbkdf2['hash'] into User table as the user's password
```

#### Logging in the user:

```php
$this->load->library('pbkdf2');
$username = $this->input->post('username', TRUE);
$password = $this->input->post('password');

# Fetch the stored user's password from the database
$user_password = $this->user_model->get_password_by($username);

# Check whether the User exists
if ($user_password)
{
    # Encrypt the new given password by using the old one:
    $pbkdf2 = $this->pbkdf2->encrypt($password, $user_password);

    # Check whether the new generated password matches the old one
    if ($pbkdf2['hash'] === $user_password) {
        # Log in the user ...
    } else {
        # Show an error...
    }
} else {
    # Show an error... 
}
```